# Компиляция .jar в другую папку (Gradle)

Tags: gradle

Как скомпилировать файл .jar в другую папку? Требуется скомпилировать без сторонних папок (папок с классами, ресурсами).
`project.buildDir = "$rootDir/directory"` мне не подходит, т.к создается папка с ненужными мне папками и файлами.

Answer (score 0):

```
jar {
    baseName('../project/myApp')
    enabled = true
}
```